# adding Signature v4 in python script using boto

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I am using an existing python 2.7 script that imports `boto`. I got the error `Requests specifying Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed keys require AWS Signature Version 4` so I am currently trying to add this using [Using boto for AWS S3 Buckets for Signature V4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27400105/using-boto-for-aws-s3-buckets-for-signature-v4) as a resource.

Some answers there advised adding this code:

```
if not boto.config.get('s3', 'use-sigv4'):
    boto.config.add_section('s3')
    boto.config.set('s3', 'use-sigv4', 'True')
```

From reading the linked docs, it seems I should add this to the config.py from botocore. I did this, but I still get the error.There's also this snippet in the docs:
Specify the following in the boto default config file:

```
[s3] use-sigv4 = True
```

I'm not clear on where to add this.

Or, it seems I could set s3 to use sigv4 by default in the cli by using:

```
aws configure set default.s3.signature_version s3v4
```

I don't have the Amazon CLI installed and am not familiar with it, so I'm wondering if there's another way I can set it to be the default version.

Comment: Is this boto or boto3?

Comment: @jarmod it's boto

Comment: Add that use-sigv4 config setup just before you create an S3 connection object in your code. You'll probably also have to add boto.config.set('s3', 'host', 's3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com') or whichever region is appropriate.

Comment: do you mean here:s3 = boto.connect_s3(
        access_key,
        secret_key,
        #use-sigv4 = True,
        calling_format = boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat(),
        )

Comment: Add the S3 section to boto.config, as you've shown (under "advised adding this code"). Add the aforementioned host config, then create your S3 connection. I would keep it simple e.g. c = boto.connect_s3(access_key, secret_key).